# present view controller ios7

Tags: ios7, xcode5, presentviewcontroller

Im using a tabBarVC and within one of the tabviews i want to present a view. I added a button. Added this code:

```
 - (IBAction)showChart:(id)sender {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    woundViewController *privacy = (woundViewController*)[storyboard     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"privacy"];

    // present
    [self presentViewController:privacy animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

The new VC I want to show has identifier "privacy" assigned to it.

but I get this error :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[flipSideViewController _setViewDelegate:]:
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the way you're setting the view controller the present code looks correct.

I would try this

```
- (IBAction)showChart:(id)sender {

woundViewController *privacy = [[woundViewController alloc]init];
// present
[self presentViewController:privacy animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: This made it so it didn't throw an error but It didn't present the view I setup in the main. It presented a black screen. I want it to go from woundVC => flipsideVC